# How to display the user name once it's submitted?

Tags: javascript

Its a simple thing i want to do but i'm new and need help. want the user to enter their name and once they do i want return a:
 `<h3>hi username</h3>`
It might be simple but not for a new person. if anyone can explain what i should do first without the answer would be great thanks in advance.

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';



 class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
      this.state = {
      input: ''
     }
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
    // setting the setState to new value

     handleClick(e){
     this.setState({
      input: this.state.input
    })
   }

   render(){

     //userName holds value 
     const userName = this.state.input;

     if(userName === 'name') {

     return <h4>hi</h4>  
  } 
  return (
     <div onSubmit={this.handleClick} style={{textAlign: "center"}}>

      <h3>User enter info</h3>

       <label>
     <input type='text' name='name' style={{ height: 20, width: 200}}/>

      </label>
   <div>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     <h3>{userName}</h3>

    </div>

  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: 1) `onsubmit` attribute can only be used with `<form>` tag. 2) never once in your code do you change the value of your `this.state.input`. You should capture the `onChange` event in your text input and use `setState` in its handler. 3) the `setState` in your `handleClick()` is redundant and does nothing.

Comment: Unrelated, but the somewhat-random indentation makes the code harder to think about.

Comment: @shkaper, thank you I appreciate the direction it helped alot. I was able to figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

On handleClick function, use the parameter you assigned:

```
 handleClick(e){
    this.setState({input: e.input});}
```